# OpenGLES 2 Generating Multiple Textures

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to follow Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on creating hills with a texture and a seperate texture for the background using OpenGLES (http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1). I am however trying to convert it to Cocos2D 2, as his tutorial is only for OpenGLES 1. I have succeeded up to a certain point, both my spriteWithColor, and stripedSpriteWithColor1 method work fine on their own, however if I create two seperate sprites and use one method after the other the one created second does not get rendered in the iOS simulator or on an actual device. I am not expert on OpenGLES, so I'm having trouble debugging this error, here's my source code:

```
-(CCSprite *)stripedSpriteWithColor1:(ccColor4F)c1 color2:(ccColor4F)c2 textureSize:(float)textureSize stripes:(int) nStripes {
    // 1: Create new CCRenderTexture
    CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureSize height:textureSize];

// 2: Call CCRenderTexture:begin

[rt beginWithClear:c1.r g:c1.g b:c1.b a:c1.a];

// 3: Draw into texture
//OpenGL gradient

NSLog(@"Strip color is: %f : %f : %f", c2.r,c2.g,c2.b);

CGPoint vertices[nStripes*6];
ccColor4F colors[nStripes*6];
int nVertices = 0;
float x1 = -textureSize;
float x2;
float y1 = textureSize;
float y2 = 0;
float dx = textureSize / nStripes * 2;
float stripeWidth = dx/2;
ccColor4F stripColor = (ccColor4F){c2.r,c2.g,c2.b,c2.a};
for (int i=0; i<nStripes; i++) {
    x2 = x1 + textureSize;
    colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
    vertices[nVertices++] = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
    colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
    vertices[nVertices++] = CGPointMake(x1+stripeWidth, y1);
    colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
    vertices[nVertices++] = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
    colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
    vertices[nVertices++] = vertices[nVertices-3];
    colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
    vertices[nVertices++] = vertices[nVertices-3];
    colors[nVertices] = stripColor;
    vertices[nVertices++] = CGPointMake(x2+stripeWidth, y2);
    x1 += dx;
}


[self.shaderProgram use];


ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position  | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);

//Gradient

float gradientAlpha = 0.2;
nVertices = 0;

vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};
vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, 0);
colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};
vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, textureSize);
colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,gradientAlpha};
vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, textureSize);
colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,gradientAlpha};





glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0, (GLsizei)nVertices);



// Highlighting

float borderWidth = textureSize/18;
float borderAlpha = 0.7f;
nVertices = 0;

vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1,1,1,borderAlpha};
vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize,0);
colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1,1,1,borderAlpha};

vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, borderWidth);
colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};
vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize,borderWidth);
colors [nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0,0,0,0};

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);



//Noise 
CCSprite *noise = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"noise.png"];
[noise setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO}];
noise.position = ccp(textureSize/2, textureSize/2);
[noise visit];


[rt end];
// Return texture sprite
return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];

}

-(CCSprite *)spriteWithColor:(ccColor4F)bgColor textureSize:(float)textureSize {

    // 1: Create new CCRenderTexture
    CCRenderTexture *newt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureSize height:textureSize];

    // 2: Call CCRenderTexture:begin
    [newt beginWithClear:bgColor.r g:bgColor.g b:bgColor.b a:bgColor.a];

    // 3: Draw into the texture

    //openGL gradient
    //ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color );

    float gradientAlpha = 0.2;
    CGPoint vertices[4];
    ccColor4F colors[4];
    int nVertices = 0;

    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, 0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, 0);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, 0};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(0, textureSize);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, gradientAlpha};
    vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(textureSize, textureSize);
    colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){0, 0, 0, gradientAlpha};

    // gradient
    [self.shaderProgram use];

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position  | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);




    CCSprite *noise = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"noise.png"];
    [noise setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO}];
    noise.position = ccp(textureSize/2, textureSize/2);
    [noise visit]; 

    // 4: Call CCRenderTexture:end
    [newt end];

    // 5: Create a new Sprite from the texture
    return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:newt.sprite.texture];

}


- (ccColor4F)randomBrightColor {

    while (true) {
        float requiredBrightness = 172;

        ccColor4B randomColor =
        ccc4(arc4random() % 255,
             arc4random() % 255,
             arc4random() % 255,
             255);
        if (randomColor.r > requiredBrightness ||
            randomColor.g > requiredBrightness ||
            randomColor.b > requiredBrightness) {
            return ccc4FFromccc4B(randomColor);
        }
    }

}

- (void)genBackground {
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    [_background removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

    ccColor4F color3 = [self randomBrightColor];
    ccColor4F color4 = [self randomBrightColor];
    CCSprite *stripes = [self stripedSpriteWithColor1:color3 color2:color4 textureSize:512 stripes:4];
    stripes.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
    ccTexParams tp2 = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
    [stripes.texture setTexParameters:&tp2];

    _terrain.stripes = stripes;
    ccColor4F bgColor = [self randomBrightColor];

    _background = [self spriteWithColor:bgColor textureSize:512];

    _background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    ccTexParams tp = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
    [_background.texture setTexParameters:&tp];

    [self addChild:_background];
}

-(id) init {
    if((self=[super init])) {
        self.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionColor];
        CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
        _terrain = [Terrain node];
        [self addChild:_terrain z:1];
        [self genBackground];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        // [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Not entirely... I removed any all openGL from the `spriteWithColor:textureSize` method which bypassed the problem and put up with the lack of a gradient, I didn't actually find a way to get both working however... :/

Comment: Also did you manage to add Box2d physics as in tutorial? Can you share if yes, since I have tons of problems and errors..

Comment: Yes I did as a matter of fact... I'll try and get around to sharing my source code over the next few days but I am pretty busy with uni work atm... If I seem to have forgotten don't hesitate to remind me!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been mega-busy with university work... I've actually come across some errors with my box2D code since testing it on an iPad (fixtures aren't deallocating memory properly) so I won't upload until I've sorted that, as you'll have the exact same problem :/